# Distinct $\frac{x}{y} \mod p$

Tags: number-theory, modular-arithmetic

Given $n \in \mathbb{N}$, define
$$
S = \left\{\frac{x}{y}: x,y \in \{0, 1, \dots, n\}, y \neq 0\right\} \subset \mathbb{Q}
$$
and, given a prime $p > n$, define $f: S \mapsto \mathbb{Z}_p$ by
$$
f\left(\frac{x}{y}\right) = xy^{-1} \mod p,
$$
where $y^{-1}$ is of course the inverse of $y$ modulo p.

Is there a prime $p$ such that $f$ is injective? Is there an easy way to find the smallest one? Or just one not much larger than $n$?

The question is motivated by a programming contest problem where, instead of dealing with floating-point arithmetic, I performed all computations modulo $p$, and the correctness of by solution depended on the function $f$ being injective.

Comment: Interesting, so what's the use to this function? It seems from the answer below that you need a really big p to contain all the information.

Comment: @Everstudent In the problem, it was given a set of points $S$ in the plane with integer coordinates with absolute value at most 300, and we needed to find a point which minimizes the number of distinct distances from $S$ to it. You can prove that the optimal solution is either the middle point between two points in $S$, or the intersection of the perpendicular bisectors of two pairs of points in $S$. So we can try all such candidates, and they all have rational coordinates. Doing a few calculations losely here, it seems $n \approx 600^3$. I chose $p = 10^9 + 7$, so I was up to luck...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This function is injective if you pick $p>2n^2$. In fact, suppose
$$xy^{-1} \equiv zw^{-1} \pmod{p}$$
This is equivalent to
$$xw-zy \equiv 0 \pmod{p}$$
In other words $p$ divides $xw-zy$. However, since $0 \le x,y,w,z \le n$ necessarily
$$-p<-2n^2 \le xw-zy \le 2n^2 <p$$
This necessarily implies that $xw-zy=0$, because there is no other multiple of $p$ between $-p$ and $p$.
But $xw-zy=0$ is equivalent to
$$\frac{x}{y}=\frac{z}{w}$$
so that the function is injective.

Comment: You can drop the factor $2$. Since $w,x,y,z$ are all nonnegative we have $-n^2 \leqslant xw-zy \leqslant n^2$. Also, since $S$ contains about $\frac{6}{\pi^2}n^2$ elements, no prime much smaller than $n^2$ can work.